# How can I update_sub_field in current row of repeater - advanced custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is image of my repeater:

[My repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGbkq.jpg)

This is my code to update subfield of repeater:

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$postid =  $_POST['post_idz'];

$repeater_value = get_post_meta($postid, 'groupon', true);
if ($repeater_value) {
  for ($i=0; $i<$repeater_value; $i++) {
    $meta_key = 'groupon_'.$i.'_booked';
    $sub_field_value = get_post_meta($postid, $meta_key, true);
  }
}

$sum = $sub_field_value + $quantity;
update_post_meta($postid, $meta_key, $sum, $sub_field_value);
```

But now, I don't know how to update it by row. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you just put the update_post_meta function into the for loop ?

Comment: My repeater has many sub fields. So when I did it, update_post_meta  influence on all of my sub fields...